# Entity framework with oracle database

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, oracle, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework with oracle database.

I downloaded the provider from http://oracleef.codeplex.com/.

Today I converted my project to work with VS2010.

Is there a way (free) to work with oracle db using VS2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try express editions of some data providers.  For example, http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/...

Answer (score 0):

Well Visual Studio (and Windows) both require paying Microsoft, so "No, you can't do it for free".

You can use Oracle XE (Express Edition) for free though.